# First Datastore query always slow

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I have a Python 3.7 project which communicates with Datastore using the google.cloud.ndb library.

I've noticed that the first request when an instance is brought up is always an order of magnitude (several seconds) slower than subsequent ones.  This is true even running locally with an emulated Datastore. I've verified that the delay is due to the first `ndb.Key(...).get()` which gets run. Presumably the Datastore connection takes some time to setup?

Has anyone found a way to reduce this delay?

Code example:

```
from flask import Flask
from google.cloud import ndb

import time

client = ndb.Client()

def ndb_wsgi_middleware(wsgi_app):
    def middleware(environ, start_response):
      with client.context():
        return wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
    return middleware

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = ndb_wsgi_middleware(app.wsgi_app)

@app.route('/main')
def main():
  now_ts = time.time()
  org = ndb.Key(Org, 1).get()
  print('Finished get in %f' % (time.time() - now_ts))
  return 'Does not exist' if org is None else 'Exists'

class Org(ndb.Model):
  pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Output after 2 `localhost:8080/main` fetches from browser (using the local datastore emulator brought up by the command `gcloud beta emulators datastore start`):

```
Finished get in 2.043116
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2019 22:41:49] "GET /main HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Finished get in 0.001995
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Oct/2019 22:41:56] "GET /main HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: I have an app written in go and the first query to the emulator happens within 300ms. Of course, the emulator itself take time (a couple of seconds) to come up if you are bringing it up along with the app.

Comment: Interesting, my first emulator query seems to always take several seconds ...

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are experiencing this behavior is because unless configured otherwise, all App Engine application shut down their instances when idle. This means that if they receive a new request, they must take time to spin back up and respond, resulting in a higher response time than they would otherwise. This is by design to avoid taking up resources and generating charges unnecessarily as instances are charged by the minute when they are running.

You can avoid this using [warm-up requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuring-warmup-requests)  which is a special type of loading request that prepares an instance before live requests are made.

Other option would be to set up [Automatic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling) on your application using modules, and setting a value for minimum idle instances. This means, if you set it up, that at least one instance will be running at all times, preventing any and all loading requests to be needed. However, as these instances are in a constant state of running, this will incur additional charges.

Comment: I don't believe the bulk of the delay is caused by App Engine instance start up.  As I mentioned, I see the same delay locally, and good old printf debugging has confirmed that the main cause is an abnormally long first datastore query.

Comment: Ok, Can you please share with us a minimal reproducible example of your setup in order to help you to redouce the delay? Please share your App Engine setup, yaml config file, database structure, a query example.

Comment: I've updated the post to include a code sample.  My app.yaml file is the trivial `runtime: python37`, and requirements.txt contains `Flask==1.1.1` and `google-cloud-ndb`

Comment: Hi, since you haven't shared your app.yaml I can't see if you are indexing the properties of your database. Please can you share the yaml config file and the database structure? Can you also explain what does the ndb.Key.get quey in your code?

Comment: I did share app.yaml in the comment above ;)  It's trivial, no indexing.  Not sure what you mean by database structure, it's just the Org class from the example.  The ndb.Key.get is used to check if the given key exists in the database (in this simply toy example, of course, it never exists).